# Populate UserForm 'Could not set the Value property'

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm having a problem populating a userform. I found some code online that does exactly what I want and the 'example' file works perfectly. When I modify it to my needs, it gives me an error message on the following line:

```
frmModifyData.Skill.Value = Application.VLookup(cmbItemName.Value, Sheets("Enrolled").Range(vrange), 1, False)
```

Here's the entire code I'm working with:

```
Dim NotNow As Boolean
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOkay_Click()
NotNow = True

N = Application.Match(Me.cmbItemName.Value, Range("AB:AB"), 0)

Cells(N, 1).Value = Me.frmEnterData.Skill.Text
Cells(N, 2).Value = Me.frmEnterData.txtCLASS.Text
Cells(N, 3).Value = Me.frmEnterData.LastName.Text

NotNow = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmbItemName_Change()
If NotNow Then Exit Sub

vrange = "FirstField"


'LINE WITH THE PROBLEM
frmModifyData.Skill.Value = Application.VLookup(cmbItemName.Value, Sheets("Enrolled").Range(vrange), 1, False)
'END OF LINE WITH THE PROBLEM (though it could affect the two lines of code below...)


frmModifyData.txtCLASS.Value = Application.VLookup(cmbItemName.Value, Sheets("Enrolled").Range(vrange), 2, False)
frmModifyData.LastName.Value = Application.VLookup(cmbItemName.Value, Sheets("Enrolled").Range(vrange), 3, False)

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

frmModifyData.cmbItemName.RowSource = "FirstField"
End Sub
```

'FirstField' is a named range that is defined this way

```
=OFFSET(Enrolled!$AB$3,0,0,COUNTA(Enrolled!$AB:$AB)-1,3)
```

Column AB holds the "Full Name" of the user. This is what I'm using to find an individual. Once I pick a name using a drop-down box on the userform, it gives me the message `Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value.`

How do I fix this so it works?

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking your code down a little and make sure your vlookup is working...

```
Dim v

v = Application.VLookup(cmbItemName.Value, Sheets("Enrolled").Range(vrange), 1, False)

If Not IsError(v) Then
    frmModifyData.Skill.Value = v
Else
    Msgbox cmbItemName.Value & " was not found!"
End If
```

Comment: Right on.  Then try `v = "Tiberius McGoo"` ... hard-code using a known value, so you can trouble-shoot that point.

Comment: Same error message, just now stops on this line `frmModifyData.Skill.Value = v`

Comment: What is `frmModifyData` ? What type of control?

Comment: frmModifyData is the name of the userform

Comment: 'Skill' is the name of a field that I want to populate in the userform. Once the 'Name' is found (from column AB) it should give me Skill, CLASS, and LastName. These are the names that were used in another userform where I enter the data. Honestly, I don't care if the name is Joe, Frank, and Fred -- as long as it works.

Comment: What type of control is it? TextBox ?  Label ?  Not every control has a Value property...

Comment: 'Skill' is a drop-down, 'CLASS' is a text box, and 'LastName' is a text box. They were all entered as text (example: frmEnterData.Skill.TEXT)

Comment: I get that error if I try to set `Value` to something which is not on the comboxbox list.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is populate the userform with data based on the username that is found in column AB. What do I need to change to make that happen?

Comment: I cant see exactly how your form is set up, so it's not really possible for me to offer more than I already added.